# How to solve this set of equations as efficiently as possible (with "efficiently" measured in FLOPS)?

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, na.numerical-analysis, numerical-linear-algebra

The system of equations is the following:
$$
\Gamma_i^{\ -1} = \sum_{i=1}^nA_{ij}\Gamma_j,
$$
where $\Gamma = (\Gamma_i)$ is a vector  of size $n$ and $A$ is a matrix of size $n\times n$, with $n \gt 100$.

So there is a [paper](https://doi.org/10/gf5dw5) (*Numerical and computational aspects of cosmo-based activity coefficient models*, Brazilian Journal of Chemical Engineering vol.36 no.1) showing, that successive substitution is faster than Newton–Raphson if solved as mentioned above.

**I was wondering if through some kind of linear algebra change the system of equations becomes easier/faster to solve?**

I don't know if it helps, but here is how the matrix $A$ is calculated (Hadamard product):
$$
A = B \circ D
$$
Where $B$ is symmetric, dense with **only** positive (<s>and negative</s>) entries and $D$ is dense with only positive entries and all rows are the same and their sum is 1.

I just corrected that $B$ is positive symmetric, and since $D$ is also positive, this would make $A$ positive. So:
$$
A_{ij}>0
$$

Comment: Are you looking for a specific solution, or any one goes? Or have you proved that the solution is unique? (Because, in general, it won't.)

Comment: For large systems, Newton methods will be very poor until you are fairly close to the minimizing point. My suspicion is that the fastest method will look (1) good heuristic for initial guess, (2) fast first-order method for a few steps, and then (3) Newton iterations till convergence. Due to your additional structure it might be possible to do more rigorously than this, of course, but generally it's pretty difficult to rigorously analyze such nonlinear systems.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I am an engineer that needs to solve this set of equations for many A with n ranging from 100-1000. Using successive substitution with damping I get all of them solved uniquely. I am however interested if it is possible to solve them more efficiently as I need to solve millions of them.

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong In some cases I am already using good initial guesses and it workd quite well. But for some cases I have no initial guess.

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong Please don't post answers in comments. Show that you are not afraid of downvotes and use the answer box. :)

Comment: *Using successive substitution with damping I get all of them solved uniquely*. What do you mean? That method returns *one* solution; of course it "solves them uniquely". However, what happens if you run the methods many times with different starting points? Does it always converge to the same solution? Or do you get multiple ones?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I don't think my comment is sufficiently detailed, nor backed by sufficient mathematical or computational evidence, to be an answer at this point.

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong Comments are meant to suggest improvements to the question. Yours is a perfectly fine answer, in my view, not a comment. Posting this kind of content as comments defeats the purpose of the reputation and upvotes system, and I think it is bad practice on SE.

Comment: @Federico tell that to Brian Conrad, who started only ever answering questions in comments, deliberately.

Comment: @DavidRoberts Well, "someone else does that, too" does not sound like a convincing argument, bud I'd be interested to learn the reasons behind that choice.

Comment: @Federico it's the difference between a 16k+ rep user telling someone with <1k rep not to be afraid of downvotes, and one of the most respected algebraic geometers of our time deciding how he wishes to voluntarily impart his deep understanding. I know why he so chose but I don't know if it's public knowledge so I'm not going to share it here. I also choose to sometimes give hints or outline answers in comments, and not because I'm afraid of downvotes.

Comment: ...and why do *you* give these hints or outline answers as comments, exactly? I don't know where the practice started, but it seems a misuse of the system to me. These "hints" cannot be downvoted even when they are completely wrong.

Comment: @Federico Mostly because I don't care about gaining rep points, and I would spend too long writing a detailed answer, more than I should. It's either give some information in a comment, or none at all.

Comment: I'd suggest to write the same information as an answer instead, even without adding details. In this way it can be accepted, for instance, downvoted if it's wrong, searched using the MO search box, edited for corrections (for instance automated fixes to dead links), etc. There are many details that simply don't work with comments.

Comment: @Federico I'll take that on board.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni, is there somethin else I could look at now that I have corrected that A is positive only?

Comment: @Simon Not that I know of. It might be easier to prove some theoretical properties, but I don't think it changes the picture significantly, if that fixed-point algorithm was already converging in a few iterations.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Well, it converges in 50-100 iterations when the starting point is not that good. But I found a way to start with better initial guesses and that accelerated a bit further. I will have a look at the theoretical properties.

Answer (score 2):

Based on what I know of similar equations, I would expect that you can't beat this "successive substitution" (essentially a non-linear Gauss-Seidel) in case where it converges fast and only few iterations are needed.

However, there are choices of the parameters for which NGS requires many iterations (when the Jacobian is close to being a singular matrix, more precisely), and then Newton (on the formulation $\operatorname{diag}(\Gamma)A\Gamma-\mathbf{1}=0$, as it is done in the paper) will become the winner.

Comment: I have to calculate the Jacobian numerically, so this makes it quite slow. (look at the paper link I added in the original question)

Comment: @Simon You solve the linear system of equations in (6), right? I wouldn't call it "calculating the Jacobian numerically"; anyhow, that costs $O(n^3)$, it's normal that it is much slower than an $O(n^2)$ iteration of the nonlinear Gauss-Seidel method. Newton takes the cake in cases when you need many iterations of the NGS method.

Comment: So basically, it is already as efficient as I can get?

Comment: @Simon For this kind of problem, I'd guess so, but it also depends on how much accuracy you need. As Christopher Wong suggests in a comment, it's a good idea to focus on the starting point instead, if you have to solve many of these problems.